# How to remove only checked div element

Tags: jquery

I want to remove only checked div element. My script removing all dynamically created div elements. What i've been doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <form>
        <p>Title:</p>
        <input type="text" id="title" />
        <p>Link:</p>
        <input type="text" id="link" />
    </form>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</div>
<div class="content" style="margin-top:50px">
    <div class="content_wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $(".btn-success").click(function () {
        var title_val = $("#title").val();
        var link_val = $("#link").val();
        $(".content").append('<div class="content_wrapper"><div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4"><ol class="breadcrumb"><h4>' + title_val + '</h4><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox"></ol><a href="http://' + link_val + '" class="thumbnail"></a></div></div>');
    });
    $(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
        if ($(".checkbox").is(":checked")) {
            $(".content_wrapper").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kani339/taw92uzz/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add the checkbox inside a wrapper, just find the `closest` ancestor of that type above the clicked checkbox:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
    $(".checkbox").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).closest(".content_wrapper").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

or (as Satpal suggested)

```
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function() {
    $(".checkbox:checked").closest(".content_wrapper").remove();
});
```

*Your HTML and code was a little puzzling in isolation (as the delete option you show appeared unrelated to the containers you added, but I get it now).* :)

Comment: Why not simple `$(".checkbox:checked").closest(".content_wrapper").remove();`?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks!